# Проблема получения JiraRestClient

Tags: java

Пишу сервис интеграции с Jira Api. Проблема возникает только при деплое сервиса на дев-стенд. Локально все отрабатывает, а на стенде сервис получает JiraRestClient ровно через раз. Схожая проблема возникает, если использовать HttpURLConnection - сервис пропускает один запрос (к одному uri), но остальные (по другим uri) валятся с time out.
Используется:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-app</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Для получения используется:

```
new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
            .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(jiraUrl), login, password);
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь)
Quarkus, подключение реализовано в клиенте:

```
  @ApplicationScoped
public class JiraClientImpl implements JiraClient {  
@Override
    public JiraRestClient getJiraRestClient(String login, String password, String jiraUrl) throws URISyntaxException {
        return new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
                .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(jiraUrl), login, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код, который некорректно работает и текст ошибки, которую Вы получаете - так будет больше шансов что Вам ответят

Comment: Дак вот нет никакой ошибки. Просто прилетает один раз null, а один раз JiraRestClient при подключении к jira с базовой аутентификацией. Некорректно работает вот та самая строчка внизу: new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory()
            .createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(jiraUrl), login, password);